# jquery scrollTop doesn't work when html and body overflow auto

Tags: jquery, html, css, overflow, scrolltop

The main problem that scrollTop() doesn't work when html and body styles looks like this:

```
html
  margin: 0
  padding: 0
  border: 0
  overflow: auto

body
  padding: 0
  margin: 0
  background-image: url('/imgs/bg1.jpg')
  overflow: auto
  background-repeat: no-repeat
```

My js code:

```
$('.get_method').click(function () {

  $('body').animate({
     scrollTop: $(".test").offset().top
  });

});
```

When I delete overflow property from html or body elements (or everywhere) all works perfectly but when I scroll document BG image ends and I get white space. All that I need is fixed BG image and working scrollTop animation effect when I click .get_method button.

EDIT:

element .test its a div element.
CSS:

```
.test
  position: relative
  top: 900px
```

Comment: If you change `$('body')` with `$(window)`?

Comment: doesn't work again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

**[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/9fe77anq/386/)**

**html**

```
 <h1>Top of the page</h1>

<article style="height: 1000px">
    <p style="margin-bottom: 600px">Scroll down the page&hellip;</p>
    <p>Then click the box.</p>
    <a href="#" class="scrollup">Scroll</a>
</article>
```

**jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $('.scrollup').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('.scrollup').fadeOut();
        }
    });

    $('.scrollup').click(function () {
        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 600);
        return false;
    });

});
```

Comment: all works well but the main problem that I cant understand how make FIXED BG. I need to scroll content with fixed bg... When I make html overflow hidden and body overflow scroll I will get fixed BG but your script doesn't work

Comment: The key point is overflow:auto or overflow:visible. I cannot find a solution.